# uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName'

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm working on a page which fetches data from XML file `riglists.xml` and then writes into `<tbody>` of a table. Used `XMLHttpRequest()` to fetch the data from the XML file. As the console log suggests it fetches the data properly but when passing through another function argument, it initializes undefined.
The function follows:

```
function loadXmlGlobal(){
        var xmlDoc="riglists.xml";
        var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open("GET",xmlDoc,true);
        xhr.send();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            return xhr.responseTest;
          }
        };
      }

      function readXML() {
        var xmlDoc = loadXmlGlobal();
        console.log(xmlDoc);
        var memberArray = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("MEMBER"); .....
```

now the `console.log(xhr.responseText);` prints the whole content of riglists.xml in console, but the `console.log(xmlDoc);` prints undefined and showing this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined 
     at readXML ((index):87)
```

Also when I'm using `xhr.responseXML` instead of `xhr.responseText` it returned nothing. Why's that?

Content of `riglists.xml` follows:

```
<LIST>
  <MEMBER>
    <USERDATA>Access Tocken</USERDATA>
    <PLATFORM>PC</PLATFORM>
    <PROCESSOR>AMD</PROCESSOR>
    <RAM>8 GB</RAM>
    <HDD>1 TB</HDD>
    <SDD>256 GB</SSD>
    <GFX>NVIDIA</GFX>
    <LIKES>0</LIKES>
  </MEMBER>
</LIST>
```

I'm using **XAMPP Version: 5.6.32** and **Google Chrome 62.0.3202.62**

Hopefully I covered all that would be needed, I know its probably something silly, but I can't nail it down.

**Update**: still no luck. Did everything by Solution page(link: [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) ) @epascarello suggested.

```
function loadXmlGlobal(callback){
        var xmlDoc="riglists.xml";
        var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) { // request is done
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
              callback(xhr.responseText);
            }
          }
        };
        xhr.open("GET",xmlDoc);
        xhr.send();
      }

      function readXML() {
        loadXmlGlobal(function (result) {
          var memberArray = result.getElementsByTagName("MEMBER");
          console.log(memberArray[0].getElementsByTagName("USERDATA")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        });
```

but now getting :
`Uncaught TypeError: result.getElementsByTagName is not a function
    at (index):95
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange ((index):85)`

Comment: So what is `testobj`? It is undefined. You can not return from an asynchronous method....

Comment: sorry my mistake. I was trying something different and forgot to delete that. fixed that. check now.

Comment: Still the same reason. You order a pizza and as soon as you hit the submit button, you try to eat the pizza. The issue is you have to wait for the pizza in order to eat it. By the time the onreadystatechange function runs, your function has already finished and return undefined. Follow the advice on the duplicate ticket on how to solve the problem so you can eat your pizza.

Comment: `xhr.open("GET",xmlDoc,true);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            return xhr.responseTest;

     xhr.send();`
I've tried this before but same issue.

Comment: BECAUSE IT IS ASYCHRONOUS. Read the duplicate answers